# Why does parsing a webpage with beautiful soup leads to src attributes of images with values as base64 strings?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to download the HTML code of a website with `requests` and parse it with `beautiful soup` to get the source code of some images I want to download.

```
import requests, bs4

res = requests.get('https://www.tutti.ch/de/li/bern?q=gartenstuhl')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
images = soup.select('div[style] > img')
for i in images:
    print(i.get('src'))
```

The problem is: I get back Data URLs, which don't seem to be useful for downloading the images.

[image]

I need every src attribute to be a link like `'https://c.tutti.ch/images/4523452354235.jpg'`. How can I get the src attributes as a normal python string data type? Is there a simple way to convert Data URLs to normal URLs?

I have found these resources from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) and [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-python/). I think it boils down to the question how to decode base64 strings.

EDIT: new code snippet

```
res = requests.get('https://www.tutti.ch/de/li/bern?q=gartenstuhl')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

#Check for errors from here
images = soup.select('div[style] > img')

for im in images:
    imageURL = im.get('src') # get the URL of the image
    print('Downloading image %s...' % (imageURL))
    res = requests.get(imageURL) # downloads the image
    res.raise_for_status()
    imageFile = open(os.path.join('tuttiBilder', os.path.basename(imageURL)), 'wb') # creates an image file
    for chunk in res.iter_content(100000): # writes to the image file
        imageFile.write(chunk)
    imageFile.close()
print('Done.')
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Those *are* the images; they were embedded directly in the webpage rather than needing a separate request for the browser to retrieve them.  Python has a base64 module that can decode these - just pass the rest of the strings after the comma.

Comment: If you WANT to scrape the URLs, but not download the images themselves, you're out of luck, because there are no URLs. If you think you want the URLs because what you REALLY WANT is to download the images themselves, then this is fine. As @jasonharper already mentioned, what you're looking at ARE the contents of the images. It's base64 encoded binary data. You just need to base64-decode it, and you have your binary data, which you save to a file - that's your image.

Comment: There should not be any sort of "decode ascii" step in the process - image data is binary, not text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7` is the GIF encoding for a one-pixel image consisting of a single black dot. So you probably don't need to go to a lot of effort to decode it.

Data URLs, which encode the contents of an HTTP data object directly into a URL (so that there is no associated file) are sometimes used to embed very small images directly into an HTML document, thereby saving the cost of requesting and receiving the small image. For small files, the overhead of the request and reply headers can be far larger than the file size itself (the single-pixel GIF is 42 bytes, for example) so it can make sense to embed the data directly, even after accounting for the fact that Base64 encoding requires four bytes to encode three bytes of data. So it is sometimes useful to be able to convert a data URL into a file.

The data URL starts with `data:` followed by a "media type", a comma, and the data string, which can only contain URL characters. The media type describes the format of the data; it consists of what's called a "mimetype" –a pair of words separated by a slash, like `image/gif` [Note 1]– possibly followed by list of attributes, each starting with a semicolon. If the last attribute is the word `base64`, the binary data has been encoded in Base-64. Data URLs without the `base64` attribute are "%-encoded" like URLs; any special character is sent as a `%` followed by two hexadecimal digits.

So a very simple-minded decoder which can only handle GIFs might look something like:

```py
import base64
import urllib.parse

def dataURI_decode(uri):
    if uri.startswith('data:'):
        dataFormat, data = uri.split(',', 1)
        mimetype, *attrs = dataFormat.split(';')
        if attrs and attrs[-1] == 'base64':
            return mimetype, base64.b64decode(data)
        else:
            return mimetype, urllib.parse.unquote_to_bytes(data)

# Sample use to save a GIF from a data url:
uri = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7'
mimetype, gif = dataURI_decode(uri)
if (mimetype == 'image/gif'):
    with open("data.gif", "wb") as f:
        f.write(gif)
```

---

#### Notes

1. There is a global registry of known mime type strings; `image/gif`, for example, identifies a GIF file (or data stream. These strings are also used to identify the file type of files being sent over HTTP (or in e-mail messages). (You don't have to use a registered mimetype string when sending a file, but it's quite possible that the browser or email client which receives the file will then handle it incorrectly.)

Answer (score -2):

You need change line 6 with this `images = soup.find_all('img')` and add all this to an array than remove *data:image/gif...*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.tutti.ch/de/li/bern?q=gartenstuhl')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
images = soup.find_all('img')

list = [img['src'] for img in images if img.has_attr('src')]

for element in list:
    if element[0] == 'd':
        list.remove(element)

print(list)
```

**output:**

```
[
'https://c.tutti.ch/images/2506797800.jpg',
'https://c.tutti.ch/images/2542095444.jpg',
'https://c.tutti.ch/images/2525772665.jpg',
'https://c.tutti.ch/images/2544845483.jpg',
'https://c.tutti.ch/images/0256568721.jpg',
'https://c.tutti.ch/images/2466120894.jpg',
'https://c.tutti.ch/images/5890425922.jpg',
'https://c.tutti.ch/images/6251267695.jpg',
'https://c.tutti.ch/images/6201238303.jpg',
'https://c.tutti.ch/images/2277802675.jpg',
'https://c.tutti.ch/images/2273705997.jpg', 
...
]
```

Comment: @aurumpurum I edit the answer hopefully it looks clear.

Comment: I am not sure if this really solves the problem…the parser returns Data URLs and I have to decode them…your code seems to remove all images that have a Data URL as value of the src attribute, if I am right.

Comment: you said that you need every src attribute to be a link like `https://c.tutti.ch/images/4523452354235.jpg` that what that above code does, so you don't need to decode anything