# How to display a bytes type image in HTML/Jinja2 template using FastAPI?

Tags: python, html, base64, jinja2, fastapi

I have a FastAPI app that gets an image from an API. This image is stored in a variable with type: `bytes`.

I want to display the image in HTML/Jinja2 template (without having to download it). I followed many tutorials but couldn't find the solution.

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
@app.get("/{id}")
async def root(request: Request, id: str):
    picture = await get_online_person()

    data = base64.b64encode(picture)  # convert to base64 as bytes
    data = data.decode()  # convert bytes to string

    # str_equivalent_image = base64.b64encode(img_buffer.getvalue()).decode()
    img_tag = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}">'.format(data)
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        "index.html", {"request": request, "img": img_tag}
    )
```

All I get in the HTML is this: (as text on the page, not from source code)

```
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQICAQECAQEBAgICAgICAgICAQICAgICAgICAgL/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQECAQEBAgICAgI
CAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgL/wgARCAQABAADASIAA
hEBAxEB/8QAHgAAAQUBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAABQIDBAYHAQgACQr/xAAcAQACAwEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAACAwABBAUGBwj/2gAMAwEAAhADEAAAAfEpwSR+a+9IPR3c7347iwscmWyYchEIJjn+MbJj/c4FFbbb9J5....................
```

Note: For people who are marking my question to a duplicate talking about urllib, I cannot use `urllib` because the image I'm getting is from ana API, and using their direct url will result in a 403 Forbidden, so I should use their python API to get the image.

Comment: I tried this tutorial: https://blog.furas.pl/python-how-to-display-image-without-saving-in-file-using-bytesio-and-base64-string-in-url-gb.html but I get the error `'bytes' object has no attribute 'getvalue'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does parsing a webpage with beautiful soup leads to src attributes of images with values as base64 strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70959330/why-does-parsing-a-webpage-with-beautiful-soup-leads-to-src-attributes-of-images)

Comment: No it does not, because in my case I cannot use urllib (please check my explanation in the edit above). Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On **server side**—as shown in the last section of [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73264904/17865804)—you should return **only** the base64-encoded string in the context of the `TemplateResponse` (without using the `<img>` tag, as shown in your question):

```py
# ...
base64_encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_bytes).decode("utf-8")
return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request,  "myImage": base64_encoded_image})
```

On **client side**, you could display the image as follows:

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ myImage | safe }}">
```

Alternative approaches can be found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71313129/how-to-render-streamable-image-on-react-coming-from-fastapi-server).